# UILabel on image

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage, uilabel

I am trying to load an image and add some text to it. my text is in a `UILabel` and i am trying to add it to a `UIImage`. I am able to add the text, but i cant seem to get it in the right size. im trying to use the feature `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;` but on large images the text comes out very small.

```
-(UILabel *)xlabel{
    if (!xlabel) {
        xlabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.setLablePosition];
        xlabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        xlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        xlabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        xlabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        xlabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    }
    return xlabel;
}

-(UIImage *) textToImage:(UIImage *) myImage{
    UIImage *watermarkedImage = nil;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(appDelegate.theImg.size);
    [myImage drawAtPoint: CGPointZero];
   [self.xlabel drawTextInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, appDelegate.theImg.size.width, appDelegate.theImg.size.height)];
    watermarkedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
    return watermarkedImage;
}
```

thank you

Comment: Justin Paulson's answer worked... but i dont want it limited to 1 line so still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` will only reduce the size of the font.  It will start with font size 17 by default, I believe, and then reduce from there if the text is too long.

You can try starting with a larger font size:

```
xlabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
```

and then it will be larger on larger images and reduce as needed for smaller images.

Also, `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` only works when `numberOfLines` is set to `1`.

See this: [UILabel Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html)

Comment: do u know of a way to do this and not limit it to 1 line?

Comment: Multiple lines is a little more problematic.  There is no way to get it to do it for you, you'll have to code it yourself to get more than one line to work.  You'd have to analyze how many characters you had and then adjust the font size accordingly.  Do you have a preset amount of lines?  Or is the number of lines dynamic based on user input?

Comment: bummer... its user input, but never more then 2 lines.

Comment: You could always cut it in half if it is going to go onto two lines and create two labels...kind of annoying, but it would work.  Otherwise, you'd have to have some sort of ranges that correlate a font size to a number of characters and adjust the font size based on the number of characters.

Comment: ya, I was trying to avoid that ^_^ Thank you